# How to uninstall "Windows XP mode" (fake Virtual PC)

Tags: windows-7

I need a virtual machine to test my software on multiple platforms. For such purpose, I wanted to install the powerful Microsoft Virtual PC, which I've been using for years.

However, microsoft seems to have released some *improvement* - [it appears as virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3702), but in fact is some sort of Windows XP mode whatever.

When downloading, I've failed to see the difference (the [proper download site is this one](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=4580)).

I've installed this "*Windows XP mode*" and soon realised my failure. So,I've downloaded the 2007 version and tried to install, but behold:
[image: Error: You must uninstall previous version of virtual PC]

Well, I see no problem with uninstaling software I've never wanted in the first place, only if I knew a way to do it. After failing to locate uninstaler in the Start menu, I've seeked in the *Add or remove programs* (later on I've found [this microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431673%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) sugesting the very same approach). Nope, it's not there. Neither "*Microsoft Virtual PC*", "*Windows Virtual PC*", "*Windowx XP Mode*" or the localised versions of the mentioned queries.

I've also located the program executable, only to find out that it's right in System32 along with milion of other executables.

Last thing is, that the program (I downloaded x64 version) does not run under my x64 Windowx 7 Home Premium. So it's just blocking me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows XP Mode is a frontend for Windows Virtual PC; while Windows XP Mode *does* show up in the installed programs list, Windows Virtual PC was [released as a *Windows Update*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431673%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (KB958559).  For that reason, it will **not** show up in the regular installed programs list, but instead in *View installed updates*.

---

Click "*View installed updates*" in Add/Remove Programs, where you should be able to find and remove Windows Virtual PC (KB958559).

Comment: I searched updates too (I have noticed the installed acting as update). I will search again more carefully.

Comment: I searched again and found it.